# Enqueue CSS Function

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating my own WordPress theme and trying to enqueue my css in functions.php

When I navigate to wp-admin/Themes it says my template is missing, I can only assume its todo with my function but I cannot see where.

My PHP files live in the themes root folder and the css is in its own folder

**Functions.php**

```
<?php

function LoadResources () {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' ); 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_style', 'LoadResources');
```

**Header.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset') ?>">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title><?php the_title() ?></title>

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

**Edit**

[image: Full Error Message]

Comment: Please post the full error. Also, there is no `'wp_enqueue_style'` action hook. You should be using `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'LoadResources' );`

Comment: `the_title()` is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct hook is `wp_enqueue_scripts`, not `wp_enqueue_style`. Change the following line

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_style', 'LoadResources');
```

to

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'LoadResources');
```

Also, function names should be lowercase letters

### EDIT

Please note, the main stylesheet of the theme **has to go** into the root folder. It **cannot** be in a subfolder. Wordpress will automatically load the main stylesheet from there

Comment: Thanks this was the issue